# Magento 2 Admin - Product Cannot Add or Edit

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p2

I just upgrade Magento 2.3.0 to Magento 2.3.5, But after installation In **Admin > Catalog  > Products** I cannot edit or Add new products, When I am trying to add or edit **Product Page** then getting below error.

**Notice: Undefined index: quantity in /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 412**

Please help me regrading about this issue. I am badly stuck in this issue.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: reindex may help you, php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: i have already done many times, but not effected.

Comment: Maybe downgrade to 2.3.0 again and then first upgrade to 2.3.1, test and see if it still works and if it works then upgrade to 2.3.2 and so on... until you found the point where it breaks and then inspect what code was added that could possibly break the code

Comment: No, actually everything is working fine in backend and frontend - only in admin product page is not opening.

Answer (score 0):

I am just speculating here..

The error is related to quantity not being set in an array that comes from the data source, this is most likely related to the MSI functionality as it was new in 2.3.
If you are not using MSI with multiple stocks you could start to try to disable it, you can follow the instructions on the devdoc for this:

https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/inventory-management/

Otherwise, I think there are some problem in either the data provider for the product_form.xml ui component or the product_form.xml itself. As the error thrown is related to the quantity field you could try to comment out the <field name="quantity" .../> nodes in your product_form.xml and see what happens.
E.g. in this file:

vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog-admin-ui/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<!--
                <field name="quantity" component="Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi/js/product/form/sources/qty" formElement="input" sortOrder="50">
                    <settings>
            ....
                    </settings>
                </field>

-->
```

However, disabling MSI if you are not using it is your best bet.
Good luck!